# why is my desktop scaled after starting in latest vivid

Tags: xorg, display, 15.04

I'm running the latest Vivid packages and in the last update I did on Monday my laptop has started to do some strange scaling behavior once the desktop starts. I can see a flash at the lightdm login screen where it goes from proper scale to zoomed in, yet I can't find any way to reset it back to a normal setup.

This is causing all of my fonts on my apps to be huge and even things like urxvt are scaled such that what used to be fine at 12pt font I have to shrink down to 6pt get to a decent size.

Any ideas where to look? I tried poking through the display settings in Unity but nothing seemed to jump out at me and xrandr isn't telling me that anyone's got a scaling factor set in there.

xrandr -q

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   2560x1440      60.0*+
   1920x1440      60.0  
   1856x1392      60.0  
   1792x1344      60.0  
   1920x1200      60.0  
   1920x1080      59.9  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```